# Python deal with resultset

Tags: python, html, resultset

Python beginner here, I want to print n links in sequence, n is unknown ,in this example I print [0] for a view, how to make it?

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(text,'html.parser')
for link in soup.select('.list-group'):
    items=link.select('a')#.to_list()
    print(endpoint+"/"+link.select('a')[0]['href'])
    #print(link.select('a'))
    print(len(items))
    print(type(items))
    print(items)
```

The output shows below:

```
http://mlg.ucd.ie/modules/COMP41680/assignment2/month-jan-001.html
12
<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>
[<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="month-jan-001.html"> January 2020  [1522]</a>, <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="month-feb-001.html"> February 2020  [1492]</a>, <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="month-mar-001.html"> March 2020  [1395]</a>, <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="month-apr-001.html"> April 2020  [1209]</a>, <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="month-may-001.html"> May 2020  [1315]</a>, <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="month-jun-001.html"> June 2020  [1376]</a>, <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="month-jul-001.html"> July 2020  [1358]</a>, <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="month-aug-001.html"> August 2020  [1254]</a>, <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="month-sep-001.html"> September 2020  [1347]</a>, <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="month-oct-001.html"> October 2020  [1395]</a>, <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="month-nov-001.html"> November 2020  [1343]</a>, <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="month-dec-001.html"> December 2020  [1220]</a>]
```

Response for a view if needed:

```
endpoint='http://mlg.ucd.ie/modules/COMP41680/assignment2'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(endpoint)
text = response.read().decode()
print(text)
```

how to print all the `href` attributes from all the anchor elements in the `.list-group` elements?

Comment: Are you asking how to print all the `href` attributes from all the anchor elements in the `.list-group` elements?

Comment: Yes, this exactly what I want

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track, but it seems you had some stuff in there from an unrelated example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

content = requests.get(
    'http://mlg.ucd.ie/modules/COMP41680/assignment2/month-jan-001.html').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
for link in soup.select('.article'):
    for item in link.select('a'):
        print(item["href"])
```

Note:

- you weren't looping over the links, only printing the first;
- it's unclear where you got '.list-group', as that's not in the content;
- similarly, the links in the content appear to be absolute, so no need for the endpoint prefix.

Because of the way `bs4` works, you can also do this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
for item in soup.select('.article a'):
    print(item["href"])
```

Comment: Thx for share, actually I want the contents from all the sublinks, something like 'month-jan-001.html' but with other months', my confusion is, should I design a loop to find all sublinks(month.html) with unknown quanity in main endpoint and then deal with all the news strories in these sublinks?

Comment: That wasn't at all clear from your question - I assume you mean the pages referenced here? http://mlg.ucd.ie/modules/COMP41680/assignment2/ The solution would be very similar to what's given above: scrape the links for the months from this page, then scrape the article links from those one at a time and collect them. Perhaps you should try to put it together and post a new question about it if you still have trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with this link `http://mlg.ucd.ie/modules/COMP41680/assignment2/month-jan-001.html` to get all the url href in list articles, and this is what i've done :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

getData = requests.get(
    'http://mlg.ucd.ie/modules/COMP41680/assignment2/month-jan-001.html').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(getData)
all_article = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "article"})
for article in all_article:
    print('')
    link = article.find('a')
    url = link.get('href')
    print(url)
```

I don't know if this will help you or not, but maybe it could give you some idea.

Comment: thx for giving some ideas, i will read some documents about find() and try again

Comment: I documented that code on my gist, thanks for make me do scrapping @JiahaoFU https://gist.github.com/harlitad/70b907f29e6b4fbce5a844c7daeda295